# How to choose the respective attachment to download in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Anyone know how to select the specific element that contain in the attachment to download as i can't able to select the respective attachment. the screenshot I have put in the below :

[image]

below is the html code for the specific container

```
   <div class="attachment-wrap">
      <!-- Comment Title -->
                  <div id="attachmentTitle-wrapTEST" class="attachmentTitle-wrap">
                    <h2>Attachments</h2>
                 </div>
      <div id="attachment-containerTEST">

<!-- Attachment Box -->

             <div class="comment-box">

            <!-- Comment Image -->
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <div class="attachmentImg">
                         <img src="downloadAttachment?attachmenturl=/secure/thumbnail/10104/_thumb_10104.png" />                      
                </div>
                </div>

      <!-- Attachment details -->
                <div  class="col-xs-10">
                  <div class="commentContent">
                    <div class="topRow">
                      <div class="username">1177A149.PNG</div>
                      <div class="commentTimeStamp">25927 KB</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottomRow">
                      <div class="commentDisplay">
                        <a href="downloadAttachment?filename=1177A149.PNG&id=10104&mimeType=image/png" target="_blank">Download</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

            </div>

             <div class="comment-box">

            <!-- Comment Image -->
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <div class="attachmentImg">
                         <img src="downloadAttachment?attachmenturl=/secure/thumbnail/10103/_thumb_10103.png" />                 
                </div>
                </div>

      <!-- Attachment details -->
                <div  class="col-xs-10">
                  <div class="commentContent">
                    <div class="topRow">
                      <div class="username">4D7746B6.PNG</div>
                      <div class="commentTimeStamp">62766 KB</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottomRow">
                      <div class="commentDisplay">
                        <a href="downloadAttachment?filename=4D7746B6.PNG&id=10103&mimeType=image/png" target="_blank">Download</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: bit confusing could you please help with mode details

Comment: @muraliselenium what is mode details? basically i wanted to download attachment of this 4D7746B6.PNG.

but i can't get select that specific elements due to it contain nested div i think. Not sure how to get that

Comment: what you want to select simple any download? or any specific download?

Comment: I wnt to download thing from this
   <div  class="col-xs-10">
                  <div class="commentContent">
                    <div class="topRow">
                      <div class="username">4D7746B6.PNG</div>
                      <div class="commentTimeStamp">62766 KB</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottomRow">
                      <div class="commentDisplay">
                        <a href="downloadAttachment?filename=4D7746B6.PNG&id=10103&mimeType=image/png" target="_blank">Download</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the below way to click the respective download link based on the attachment name

**Code:**

```
        //Expected attachment filename needs to be specified here.
        var expectedFileName = "1177A149.PNG";

        //This list will hold all the available attachment section details
        IList<IWebElement> attachmentList = _driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comment-box"));

        foreach(var element in attachmentList)
        {

            var attachmentFilename = element.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='username']")).Text;

            if(attachmentFilename == expectedFileName)
            {
                //If the actual file name and expected file name matches, then corresponding download link will be clicked
                element.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a")).Click();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: thanks is working but however i dont know why the file downloaded twice instead of one time

Comment: Whether the duplicate attachment name exist in application?If not, Could you please check and confirm the behavior manually?

Comment: yes duplicate but is not in the same attachment container. but it will affect? as i tot getting it by xpath it won't affect as it will be obtain in the specific container only

Comment: Here, we are iterating all the container and then performing the download action.So, If you want to download only one link, then break statement will solve the problem. Please use the updated answer

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick arrow, If you are satisfied with an answer and also give the upvote

Answer (score 0):

You an create xpath specific to png name. see here

```
  //a[contains(@href,'downloadAttachment?filename=4D7746B6.PNG')]
```

It will point to download link having filename=4D7746B6.PNG

Comment: tried. not working. Error Message: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible

Comment: could you verify locator in browser console like $x("//a[contains(@href,'downloadAttachment?filename=4D7746B6.PNG')]") works fine for me. is it in any iframe tag? please try with some wait or sleep

Comment: how to search for the locator?

Comment: in ur webpage say ur in chrome, press f12, in displayed tabs select console, there you can write > $x("//a[contains(@href,'downloadAttachment?filename=4D7746B6.PNG')]")  and press Enter